# NodeJS equivalent to Blowfish 448 key in Java

Tags: java, node.js, blowfish

In our team we need to move from Java to NodeJS and there's one endpoint in an API that generates a Blowfish key 448 bits length.

We have tried to replicate it in NodeJS but we have not found a way to generate a key with 448 bits length.

The original code is this one:

```
Provider sunJce = new SunJCE();
Security.addProvider(sunJce);
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("Blowfish");
kgen.init(448);
byte[] raw = key.getBytes();
SecretKeySpecskeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "Blowfish");
```

What we think is the equivalen with crypto module is:

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var cipher = crypto.createCipher('bf-ecb', key);
```

Are we even in the right direction?

Comment: bcrypt in npm could help ypu https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt

Comment: Thanks canillas. Gonna take a look.